# .load() doesn't execute JavaScript in loaded HTML file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

My .load() doesn't execute JavaScript in loaded HTML file.

I already try the answers in anothers same thread but I can't solve my issue.

Here is my code :

**index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(empty($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        $_SESSION = array();
        //setcookie('auth', 'nop^^' , time() - 3600, '/', $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], false, true);
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: ../../frontsite/index.php');
        exit();
    }

    function menu_mode($requestUri)
    {
        $user_type = $_SESSION['admin'];
        if ($user_type == $requestUri)
            echo 'class="menu_section show"';
        else {
            echo 'class="menu_section hidden"';
        }
    }
    switch ($_SESSION['admin']) {
      case "admin":

          $pages = array(
            'admin_tableau_bord'          => 'admin_tableau_bord',
            'admin_conseilleres_liste'  => 'admin_conseilleres_liste',
            'admin_conseilleres_gestion'=> 'admin_conseilleres_gestion',
            'admin_liste_clients'         => 'admin_liste_clients'
            );

          $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'admin_tableau_bord';

          if(!array_key_exists($page, $pages)) {
            $page = 'admin_tableau_bord';
          }

          break;
      case "user":

          $pages = array(
            'cons_tableau_bord'         => 'cons_tableau_bord',
            'cons_planning'             => 'cons_planning',
            'cons_liste_clients'         => 'cons_liste_clients',
            'cons_gestion_clients'       => 'cons_gestion_clients'
            );

          $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'cons_tableau_bord';

          if(!array_key_exists($page, $pages)) {
            $page = 'cons_tableau_bord';
          }

          break;
    }
    require_once('../../frontsite/pages/db_connect.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     ALL META & LINKS
</head>
<body class="nav-md">
<div class="container body">

... blablabla ... 

           <?php
              // affichage des liens du menu
              $i="0";
              foreach($pages as $key => $value) {
                $en_cours = ($key == $page) ? ' id="en_cours"' : ''; // test page en cours
                    $href[$i] = ' href="#" data-target="'.$key.'"'.$en_cours;
                $i += 1;
              }
            ?>

            <h3>Administrateur</h3>
            <ul class="nav side-menu">
              <li><a class="dyn_link" <?php echo $href[0]; ?>><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Tableau de bord </a></li>
              <li><a><i class="fa fa-female"></i> Conseillères <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav child_menu">
                  <li><a class="dyn_link" <?php echo $href[1]; ?>>Liste</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dyn_link" <?php echo $href[2]; ?>>Gestion</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a class="dyn_link" <?php echo $href[3]; ?>><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Liste clients </a></li>

... blablabla ... 

    <!-- page content -->
    <div class="right_col" id="content_include" role="main">
      <?php
        include("../production/pages/$page.inc.php");
      ?>
    </div>

... blablabla ... 

    <!-- Include jQuery + ALL OTHER SCRIPT  -->
    <script src="../production/lib/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Load content Scripts -->
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       // Set trigger and container variables
       var trigger = $('.dyn_link'),
           container = $('#content_include');

       // Fire on click
       $(document.body).on('click','.dyn_link', function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         // Set $this for re-use. Set target from data attribute
         target = $(this).data('target');

         // Load target page into container
         container.load('./' + target + '.inc.php');

         // Stop normal link behavior
         return false;
       });

     });
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

My incuded files just contain html code.
I am sure i make mistake in my way to load the content included.

Sorry for the heavy block but you have all the infos to help me if possible.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: From what I can remember from jQuery, any javascript placed in the HEAD section of your HTML won't get executed, but any in your BODY will.

Comment: Thats wrong Keith. jquery will execute anywhere you have it in the DOM. So long as the jquery.js include is 'before' any other js code that uses jQuery or $. There is opinions on where its 'better' to put the actual `script` blocks... but neither of them have impact on this question's issue.

Comment: @IncredibleHat  `From what I can remember`,  yeah,.. Not really using jQuery that much these days, it's most likely the bit about fragments and script executing I'm thinking about.  Whenver I have used `load` for page fragments the html has also been without any `HEAD` / `HTML` tagging.  eg.  just doing load of `<b>bold<script>...</script></b>` etc..

Comment: @Nabla... what does your browser's developers tool -> network tab say when you click on `dyn_link` elements? Is it firing off a request? If so: what is the content returned? If not: is there any errors in the console?

Comment: I reduced my codeblock. @IncredibleHat . I use chrome debug. I got no errors. My html page is loaded but the javascript required is not executed.

Comment: So what does the loaded HTML page source look like, in Chrome you can go to network tab and it should show you the HTML that it just loaded.

Comment: I'm seeing multiple `id="en_cours"` ... html `id` must be unique in the entire html document (probably not your issue since you hook on .dyn_link). Also missing a `var ` in front of `target = `... and I'd change `$(document.body).on('click','.dyn_link'...` to just `$('body').on('click','.dyn_link'...` ... and then the only other thing I can suggest is "are the paths right and exist for each ./page.inc.php"?

Comment: The loaded htm page source is just a form. Only html. But this page need a script in index.php.

Comment: Oh... so the .loaded content contains MORE script to execute? Could you supply an example of like `cons_tableau_bord.inc.php` ?

Comment: No. I did this before but, its finally duplicate the script (because i need these scripts in my index.php and the included file), what is bad. So i removed the scripts needed. Like I said, the included file just contain a form.

Comment: Alright. I re-edited the post because you clipped a bit too much from the original ;) I'm starting to believe the real issue is something much more rooted in the new content and scripts and event handlers. If you are loading in more content dynamically, other event handlers may not be spotting the new content.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot and sorry for my bad english:)